# Scatter a matrix that process n gets every nth row in mpi

Tags: matrix, mpi

I want to distribute a N x N matrix so that every process P gets every P-th row. For example if I have 4 processes, process 0 has every 4th row starting from 0, process 1 has every 4th row starting from 1 and so on.

Comment: You may call `MPI_Scatter()` many times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a combination of MPI datatypes and a scatter call. If you use a MPI vector type, you can set the stride to be the size of 4 rows to skip the other three that you don't want to send.

Then you can just do an `MPI_Scatter` and have the count be the size of your matrix divided by 4.